# How to convert a []byte to a integer

Tags: go

I'm trying to convert a slice of bytes to an integer and it just does  not work:

https://play.golang.org/p/61Uhllz_qm7

For two perfectly different slices of bytes, I get the same `uint64` when I use this algorithm:

```
func idFromPacket(response []byte) uint64 {
    fmt.Printf("The slice is [%v]\n", response)
    var id uint64
    reader := bytes.NewReader(response)
    binary.Read(reader, binary.BigEndian, &id)
    fmt.Printf("The id is [%d]\n", id)
    return id
}
```

Can someone please tell me, why for different `[]byte` input to `idFromPacket` I get the same output?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone please tell me, why for different `[]byte` input to `idFromPacket` I get the same output?

Because `uint64` is 64 bits (8 bytes) long and you're passing 80 bits (10 bytes).

That is 2 bytes wider than necessary.

Then `binary.Read` reads first 8 bytes, which are all zeroes in both inputs and returns you `0` in both cases as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, you can replace your function with this one:

```golang
func idFromPacket(response []byte) uint64 {
    fmt.Printf("The slice is [%v]\n", response)
    var id uint64
    for _, v := range response {
        id <<= 8
        id |= uint64(v)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The id is [%v]\n", id)
    return id
}
```

Comment: In your example, your byte slice is too big, You have to shrink it to 8 elements. (eg. 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1). With the method above, this limitation doesn't apply.

Comment: "this limitation doesn't apply" --- sure, because your function does not follow the semantics anymore. There is a defined memory layout for `uint64`. PS: I'm not the OP.

Comment: thanks @MarvinJWendt My slice is to big because the slice contains the "header" of the packet. I should only use the ID part :) :) hahaha thank you kindly!!!